# Removing duplicate data from columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with this code:

```
Sub text() 

Dim iListCount As Integer 
Dim x As Variant 
Dim iCtr As Integer

' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro. 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Get count of records to search through (list that will be deleted). 
iListCount = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through the "master" list. 
For Each x In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) 
      ' Loop through all records in the second list. 
      For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1 
         ' Do comparison of next record. 
         ' To specify a different column, change 1 to the column number. 
         If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 3).Value Then 
         ' If match is true then delete row. 
          Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, 1).EntireRow.Delete 
          End If 
        Next iCtr 
Next 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
MsgBox "Done!" 
End Sub
```

It runs, and kind of works. It removes one duplicate but leaves all of the others. I am testing this so I'm using a small sample size, so I know that there are 5 duplicates, however I can't get this code to remove them all. Any ideas? I think its an issue with the loop but no matter what I change I can't get it to work

Comment: What does your data set look like in excel?

Comment: You are comparing Column A to column C and looking for duplicates is this what you intended? e.g. x.value is A1 and cells(ictr,3) is C1

Comment: So you are trying to remove all rows where a value in column C occurs somewhere in column A?

Comment: did you run this step by step, and see what happens after it deletes the second duplicate? Also your code can only handle it when the duplicate is in the same row as the data you are checking, perhaps that is the problem and you need to add another loop that loops through the column  you are checking against.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, basically column A is a list of product codes (5 digit number), column C is product codes that have been ordered in. However my boss wants any new product codes listed in column C added onto column A. So I think the easiest way to do this is to compare column A to column C, remove all duplicates then add the rest to column A. The code above is my attempt at the comparison part. When I step through the code, I don't receive any error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deleting entire rows in the inner loop you are modifying the range that the outer loop is looping through in the middle of the loop. Such code is difficult to debug.

Your nested loop structure is essentially a series of linear searches. This makes the overall behavior quadratic in the number of rows and can slow the application to a crawl. One approach is to use a `dictionary` which can be used in VBA if your project includes a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (Tools - References in the VBA editor)

The following sub uses a dictionary to delete all cells in column C which have a value that occurs in column A:

```
Sub text()
    Dim MasterList As New Dictionary
    Dim iListCount As Integer
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim iCtr As Integer
    Dim v As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Get count of records in master list
    iListCount = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Load Dictionary:
    For iCtr = 1 To iListCount
        v = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(iCtr, "A").Value
        If Not MasterList.Exists(v) Then MasterList.Add v, ""
    Next iCtr

    'Get count of records in list to be deleted
    iListCount = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through the "delete" list.
        For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1
            If MasterList.Exists(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, "C").Value) Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCtr, "C").Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next iCtr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: I only need to delete the duplicate cell, I don't need to delete the row but anytime I try to change it to something else I get error messages

Comment: @ColmDonnelly Try this modified version. It deletes all cells from Column C which have values which appear in Column A, and shifts the remaining cells up.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to loop through the cells, use [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and [FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff196143.aspx) to find the duplicates and add them to a range using [Union()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff834621.aspx).  You could then delete that range at the end of the routine.  This solves the problem with deleting rows as you iterate over them, and should execute pretty quickly.

Note:  This code is untested, you may need to debug it.

```
Sub text() 

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastCell as Range
    Dim masterList as Range
    Dim matchCell as Range
    Dim removeUnion as Range
    Dim firstMatch as String

    ' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro. 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("sheet2").Range("A:A")
    ' Find the last cell with data in column A
        Set lastCell = .Find("*", .Cells(1,1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    ' Set the master list range to the used cells within column A
        Set masterList = .Range(.cells(1,1) , lastCell)
    End With

    ' Loop through the "master" list. 
    For Each cell In masterList
    ' Look for a match anywhere within column "C"
         With cell.Parent.Range("C:C")
             Set matchCell = .Find(.Cells(1,1), cell.Value, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)

             'If we got a match, add it to the range to be deleted later and look for more matches
             If Not matchCell is Nothing then

                 'Store the address of first match so we know when we are done looping
                 firstMatch = matchCell.Address

                 'Look for all duplicates, add them to a range to be deleted at the end
                 Do 
                     If removeUnion is Nothing Then
                         Set removeUnion = MatchCell
                     Else
                         Set removeUnion = Application.Union(removeUnion, MatchCell)
                     End If
                     Set MatchCell = .FindNext
                 Loop While (Not matchCell Is Nothing) and matchCell.Address <> firstMatch
              End If
              'Reset the variables used in find before next loop
              firstMatch = ""
              Set matchCell = Nothing

         End With

    Next 

    If Not removeUnion is Nothing then removeUnion.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    MsgBox "Done!" 
End Sub
```